# mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'OR', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, syntax-error, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create this table, but I can't identify where the error is. Please help me, the error message doesn't seem clear to me.
Is there a comma or other character wrong?

This is the message:

**line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'OR', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'**

This is the code:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.credito ( 
  `idade` int,
  `sexo` string,
  `dependentes` int,
  `escolaridade` string,
  `estado_civil` string,
  `salario_anual` string,
  `tipo_cartao` string, 
  `qtd_produtos` bigint,
  `iteracoes_12m` int,
  `meses_inativo_12m` int,
  `limite_credito` float,
  `valor_transacoes_12m` float,
  `qtd_transacoes_12m` int 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION <s3://credito-modulo8-jess/credito8.csv>
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I've already reviewed the commas, I've looked for reserved words, but I couldn't identify where the error is.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Code is text and post it as one so others can easily copy-paste and try to repro your error. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following -

```sql
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.credito ( 
  `idade` int,
  `sexo` string,
  `dependentes` int,
  `escolaridade` string,
  `estado_civil` string,
  `salario_anual` string,
  `tipo_cartao` string, 
  `qtd_produtos` bigint,
  `iteracoes_12m` int,
  `meses_inativo_12m` int,
  `limite_credito` float,
  `valor_transacoes_12m` float,
  `qtd_transacoes_12m` int 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://credito-modulo8-jess/credito8.csv'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

-- Changing the Location Parameter in the query to have quotes instead of angular brackets.

Comment: Also, if it still doesn't work, try providing the table name without the schema.

Comment: Thanks, I got it by changing the query parameter from location to quotes, as you suggested!